# Changing space between atoms in Chemabove

Tags: spacing, fontspec, chemfig

Consider this example:

```
  \documentclass{memoir}
  \usepackage{fontspec}
  \usepackage{chemfig}
  \usepackage{unicode-math}
  \pdfmapline{+arial arial <8r.enc <sAarial.ttf}
  \begin{document}
  \setmainfont{arial}
  \setmathfont[range=\mathup] {arial}

  \chemfig{HO-[:30]**6(---(-\Chemabove[6pt]{N}{H}-[:-30](=[6]O)-[:30])---)}
  \end{document}
```

[image]

The N lies more or less on top of the H. How can I increase this distance?

---

EDIT: As seen in example below. For some reason the optional argument do not behave as expected. At least not with my font set up.

```
  \documentclass{memoir}
  \usepackage{fontspec}
  \usepackage{chemfig}
  \usepackage{unicode-math}
  \pdfmapline{+arial arial <8r.enc <sAarial.ttf}
  \begin{document}
  \setmainfont{arial}
  \setmathfont[range=\mathup] {arial}

  \chemfig{HO-[:30]**6(---(-\Chemabove[24pt]{N}{H}-[:-30](=[6]O)-[:30])---)}
  \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You could try something like `\Chemabove{N}{\raisebox{0.6ex}{H}}`.

Comment: Clever. That worked very well actually.

Comment: Do you think I should turn my comment into an answer?

Comment: Yea, I mean there could be some setting somewhere but this solution was so easy so yea I think it should be turned into an answer

Comment: Do you need to use arial?

Comment: Need is a strong word. But let's say I want to because it's going into a context where the sans serif font is arial and I see no reason for this illustration to stand out by using another font.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One quick solution would be to use `\raisebox`:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}
\chemfig{HO-[:30]**6(---(-\Chemabove[6pt]{N}{H}-[:-30](=[6]O)-[:30])---)}
\chemfig{HO-[:30]**6(---(-\Chemabove[6pt]{\raisebox{1ex}{N}}{\raisebox{1ex}{H}}-[:-30](=[6]O)-[:30])---)}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The optional arguments of `\chemabove` and `\chembelow` do exactly that! Citing `chemfig`'s manual:

> The macros `\chemabove[<dim>]{<code>}{<stuff>}` and
>   `\chembelow[<dim>]{<code>}{<stuff>}` place the `<stuff>` above and below
>   the `<code>` respectively at a vertical distance `<dim>`, without changing
>   the bounding box of `<code>`. The optional argument allows, if written,
>   to specify this dimension at each call. If the optional argument is
>   not used, a default size will be taken: its value is `1.5pt` but it can
>   be modified with the macro `\setstacksep{<dimension>}`. These commands
>   are independent of the macro `\chemfig` and can be used either inside or
>   outside its argument.

Notice the

> without changing the bounding box of `<code>`

part which is exactly what sets these macros apart from the uppercase versions `\Chemabove` and `\Chembelow` which *do* change the bounding box! (There is another pair of macros with the same difference: `\lewis` and `\Lewis`.)

Let's see that it works.

---

The default distance (`1.5pt`):

```
\documentclass[margin=.75cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}

\chemfig{HO-[:30]**6(---(-\chemabove{N}{H}-[:-30](=[6]O)-[:30])---)}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

A larger distance (`5pt`):

```
\documentclass[margin=.75cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}

\chemfig{HO-[:30]**6(---(-\chemabove[5pt]{N}{H}-[:-30](=[6]O)-[:30])---)}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

A larger distance (`5pt`) and `\Chemabove` - notice that `N` is no longer correctly placed with respect to the bonds due to the changed bounding box:

```
\documentclass[margin=.75cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}

\chemfig{HO-[:30]**6(---(-\Chemabove[5pt]{N}{H}-[:-30](=[6]O)-[:30])---)}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It's very intresting that you say so because that is what I thought too. However I had some major problems with getting that to work. Will look into it further and update the question accordingly real-soon-now™

Comment: I suspect your problems have something to do with your font settings which I didn't use as I haven't arial available and which are the only real difference in your MWE and mine

Comment: Yea most probably that is the case.

Comment: However. I think perhaps in most cases one do not want to change the bounding box and in fact keep the N at it's original place. Maybe I am missing some situation though...

Comment: @jonalv True. That's why I pointed to the difference of `\chemabove` and `\Chemabove`