# Zero length bond in chemfig?

Tags: chemfig

[image]

As you can clearly see in the high quality diagram above, I'm looking for a way to get the nitrogen and hydrogen bonded like that in chemfig.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for `\chemabove{<atom>}{<above>}`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}

\chemfig{R^1-[:30]\chemabove{N}{H}-[:-30]R^2}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Just for the record: there's also `\chembelow{<atom>}{<below>}`. I've described them in a little more detail in [my answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/107774/5049) to “[Changing space between atoms in Chemabove](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/107733/5049)”