# chemfig: Addition with \chemabove is not counted as part of the picture

Tags: chemfig

Additions with `\chemabove` or `\chembelow` seem to be not considered part of the picture.

```
\documentclass[margin=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
\chemfig{HO-[:30]**6(---(-\chemabove{N}{H}-[:-30](=[6]O)-[:30])---)}
\end{document}
```

*(Code adapted from [Changing space between atoms in Chemabove](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107733/changing-space-between-atoms-in-chemabove). Compiled with `xelatex`.)*

[image: result]

In a standalone file, the `\chemabove`/`\chembelow` part of the figure can be (partially) missing in the output (as in this example). In the middle of a larger file, it might result in too small figure margins.

Comment: IIRC there is an uppercase version `\Chemabove` which does...

Comment: `\Chemabove` would place the N too low.

Comment: @Ross While that may solve the solution for `standalone` class, Wolfram is also asking about the use of `\chemabove` in a larger file (something like an article class, for example). I might add that that solution is also not ideal, as you either end up with uneven spacing around the molecule, or you have to pass individual border margins (top, bottom, left, right) to `standalone` in an attempt to make the margins even, which is tedious and inexact.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may try to draw an invisible bond to place the H above the N, instead of using the `\chemabove` command. I've adapted the `\nobond` command provided in the `chemfig` manual into a command I call `\above`, which may or may not be more cumbersome to type than `\chemabove`.

```
%!TeX program = xelatex
\documentclass[margin=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\definesubmol\above{-[2,0.3,,,draw=none]}% adaptation of \nobond from chemfig manual

\begin{document}
\chemfig{HO-[:30]**6(---(-N(!\above H)-[:-30](=[6]O)-[:30])---)}
\end{document}
```

[image: above]

This solution is of course adaptable to replicate the results of `\chembelow`, perhaps with `\definesubmol\below{-[6,0.3,,,draw=none]}`.